# Why do HTML and JS feel slow on smartphones? What could be changed to make them faster?

Tags: architecture, html, rendering, file-formats

HTML rendering and javascript engines are very optimized, so why do they feel slow on smartphones?

It seems that HTML's low performance justified the creation of mobiles "apps" which are more responsive, but also did not allow developers to just do things in HTML.

It seems that websites are generally too heavy/cluttered/bloated, which makes it harder for smartphone processors to render them fast enough, but it doesn't seem like it's the only real reason.

I've read that HTML is known to be an ambiguous language, which makes it harder to render it since browsers have to lift ambiguity and render malformed HTML.

XHTML seems like a "stricter" standard, but it seems like it was abandoned. Would a more strict markup language be faster to render?

What other option would there be for a markup language to be faster to render?

- Would it be possible to reduce clutter by collapsing redundant tags before sending the HTML?
- Would "compiling" the tag tree-architecture into a binary format make it faster to render?

Does the DOM generally carries too much technical debt, which explains its poor performance?

Comment: While this is a conceptual question about software engineering, it is highly subjective, and therefore not a good fit for this community.

Comment: where else could I ask this question? and how is this subjective? html+js is slower than apps.

Comment: The question of how to make web sites run faster is not sufficiently defined to provide a comprehensive answer. Everyone will have a different and valid suggestion, thus making this question opinion-based, which is off-topic from this community.

Comment: Parsing is cheap, a lot of that slowness can probably be attributed to network latency. Modern sites, in particular single-page-applications, can be tremendously unoptimized, requiring many requests for the site to load. For example, there might be a dependency chain HTML → JS for SPA → JS for specific components → content from REST API → embedded resources like images, fonts, …. This is even slower when content is loaded from multiple domains like CDNs (DNS resolution → TLS negotiation → actual HTTP request). Mobile devices tend to have slow and flaky connections, making latency noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really to do with HTML itself, and especially not XHTML, but four things:

- the document layout is dynamically computed at runtime based on the size of the device viewport.
- the attributes (including ones which affect the layout!) have to be computed at runtime from the CSS
- quite a lot of modern webpages isn't in the HTML at all, but is dynamically generated at runtime by Javascript and then added to the DOM. This triggers a re-layout and re-render. Potentially *many* re-layout and re-render events.
- advertising and tracking systems issue a lot of requests in the background, and potentially trigger yet more re-renders.

If you construct a raw HTML page with simple CSS, you will observe it rendering pretty quickly on a phone. Conversely, if you look at a web page in a desktop browser and open the development tools, you'll see an awful lot of complexity.

Much of this is down to the choice of various Javascript frameworks such as React. React components usually don't exist in the initial HTML and are constructed at runtime by Javascript. There are some efforts to combat their terrible performance by "precompiling" dynamic data back into the HTML that's originally delivered. This process is called "hydration".